# How do I read the radio button value without clicking in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

What is the best way to read a radio button when it is already selected in tkinter Python.

I have a function in main loop, Radio button is used to call other functions, this process is run in `While1:` loop, problem is I have to select the radio button in each time of processing. is there any method to select the earlier selected radio button value, unless radio button is not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use mainloop instead of a infinite while loop.
Here is an example that prints the value of the selected radiobutton, every second:

```
from tkinter import *


def read_value(e):
    print(v.get())
    master.after(1000, read_value, 'dummy')


master = Tk()

v = IntVar()
v.set(1)

r1 = Radiobutton(master, text="One", variable=v, value=1)
r1.pack(anchor=W)
r2 = Radiobutton(master, text="Two", variable=v, value=2)
r2.pack(anchor=W)

read_value('dummy')

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: i'm struck in a code can you help to solve it, if i put it here.

Comment: Yes, I, or someone else can help you: You need to ask a new question, and post your code there, with all relevant details. I'll be happy to answer, and help you.

Comment: can you please help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113262/how-do-i-satisfy-the-my-scope-using-tkinter-using-python